how to fix grafana pod log status 302
I'm keep getting the same logs of grafana pod in kubernetes
ferer= handler=notfound
logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= t=2024-05-03T09:50:30.250117271Z level=info msg="Request Completed" method=GET path=/psnlink/.env status=302 remote_addr=54.x.x.x time_ms=0 duration=79.021µs size=29
referer= handler=notfound
--
logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= t=2024-05-03T09:50:49.817726459Z level=info msg= error="[auth.unauthorized] cannot authenticate request" remote_addr=54.x.x.x traceID=
logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= t=2024-05-03T09:50:49.817839634Z level=info msg="Request Completed" method=GET path=/api/info.php status=401 remote_addr=54.x.x.x time_ms=0 duration=162.584µs size=10
2 referer= handler=notfound
logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= t=2024-05-03T09:50:49.924697866Z level=info msg= error="[auth.unauthorized] cannot authenticate request" remote_addr=54.x.x.x traceID=
logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= t=2024-05-03T09:50:49.924840103Z level=info msg="Request Completed" method=GET path=/api/phpinfo.php status=401 remote_addr=54.x.x.x time_ms=0 duration=263.374µs size
=102 referer= handler=notfound
logger=ngalert.scheduler t=2024-05-03T09:50:50.002092145Z level=debug msg="Alert rules fetched" rulesCount=0 foldersCount=0 updatedRules=0
--
logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= t=2024-05-03T09:51:18.173191592Z level=info msg= error="[auth.unauthorized] cannot authenticate request" remote_addr=54.x.x.x traceID=
logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= t=2024-05-03T09:51:18.17327696Z level=info msg="Request Completed" method=GET path=/api/.env.local status=401 remote_addr=54.x.x.x time_ms=0 duration=128.617µs size=1
02 referer= handler=notfound
logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= t=2024-05-03T09:51:18.242438872Z level=info msg= error="[auth.unauthorized] cannot authenticate request" remote_addr=54.x.x.x traceID=
logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= t=2024-05-03T09:51:18.24252404Z level=info msg="Request Completed" method=GET path=/api/.env.production status=401 remote_addr=54.x.x.x time_ms=0 duration=116.236µs s
ize=102 referer= handler=notfound
logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= t=2024-05-03T09:51:18.323460276Z level=info msg= error="[auth.unauthorized] cannot authenticate request" remote_addr=54.x.x.x traceID=
logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= t=2024-05-03T09:51:18.323537866Z level=info msg="Request Completed" method=GET path=/api/.env.staging status=401 remote_addr=54.x.x.x time_ms=0 duration=205.437µs siz
e=102 referer= handler=notfound
logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= t=2024-05-03T09:51:18.3926694Z level=info msg= error="[auth.unauthorized] cannot authenticate request" remote_addr=54.x.x.x traceID=
logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= t=2024-05-03T09:51:18.392744884Z level=info msg="Request Completed" method=GET path=/api/src/.env status=401 remote_addr=54.x.x.x time_ms=0 duration=127.502µs size=10
2 referer= handler=notfound
logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= t=2024-05-03T09:51:18.463180935Z level=info msg= error="[auth.unauthorized] cannot authenticate request" remote_addr=54.x.x.x traceID=
logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= t=2024-05-03T09:51:18.463251735Z level=info msg="Request Completed" method=GET path=/apis/.env status=401 remote_addr=54.x.x.x time_ms=0 duration=118.784µs size=102 r
eferer= handler=notfound
logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= t=2024-05-03T09:51:18.536681664Z level=info msg= error="[auth.unauthorized] cannot authenticate request" remote_addr=54.x.x.x traceID=
logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= t=2024-05-03T09:51:18.536746027Z level=info msg="Request Completed" method=GET path=/apis/.env.local status=401 remote_addr=54.x.x.x time_ms=0 duration=112.732µs size=102 referer= handler=notfound
logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= t=2024-05-03T09:51:18.611141967Z level=info msg= error="[auth.unauthorized] cannot authenticate request" remote_addr=54.x.x.x traceID=
logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= t=2024-05-03T09:51:18.611205107Z level=info msg="Request Completed" method=GET path=/apis/.env.production status=401 remote_addr=54.x.x.x time_ms=0 duration=109.701µs size=102 referer= handler=notfound
logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= t=2024-05-03T09:51:18.687802421Z level=info msg= error="[auth.unauthorized] cannot authenticate request" remote_addr=54.x.x.x traceID=
logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= t=2024-05-03T09:51:18.687872773Z level=info msg="Request Completed" method=GET path=/apis/.env.staging status=401 remote_addr=54.x.x.x time_ms=0 duration=122.038µs size=102 referer= handler=notfound
logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= t=2024-05-03T09:51:18.755128409Z level=info msg="Request Completed" method=GET path=/app-order-client/.env status=302 remote_addr=54.x.x.x time_ms=0 duration=72.432µs size=29 referer= handler=notfound
--
logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= t=2024-05-03T09:51:31.795816095Z level=info msg="Request Completed" method=GET path=/error/.env status=302 remote_addr=54.x.x.x time_ms=0 duration=67.867µs size=29 referer= handler=notfound
logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= t=2024-05-03T09:51:31.866294612Z level=info msg="Request Completed" method=GET path=/errors/.env status=302 remote_addr=54.x.x.x time_ms=0 duration=67.642µs size=29 referer= handler=notfound
logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= t=2024-05-03T09:51:31.938726029Z level=info msg="Request Completed" method=GET path=/example/.env status=302 remote_addr=54.x.x.x time_ms=0 duration=67.49µs size=29 referer= handler=notfound
logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= t=2024-05-03T09:51:32.022829996Z level=info msg="Request Completed" method=GET path=/export/.env status=302 remote_addr=54.x.x.x time_ms=0 duration=83.377µs size=29 referer= handler=notfound
--
logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= t=2024-05-03T09:52:23.321140729Z level=info msg= error="[auth.unauthorized] cannot authenticate request" remote_addr=54.x.x.x traceID=
logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= t=2024-05-03T09:52:23.321205678Z level=info msg="Request Completed" method=GET path=/api-config.ini status=401 remote_addr=54.x.x.x time_ms=0 duration=121.609µs size=102 referer= handler=notfound
logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= t=2024-05-03T09:52:23.386788724Z level=info msg="Request Completed" method=GET path=/customer/.env status=302 remote_addr=54.x.x.x time_ms=0 duration=73.203µs size=29 referer= handler=notfound
--
logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= t=2024-05-03T09:53:05.747477859Z level=info msg= error="[auth.unauthorized] cannot authenticate request" remote_addr=54.x.x.x traceID=
logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= t=2024-05-03T09:53:05.747548954Z level=info msg="Request Completed" method=GET path=/api/index.php/v1/config/application status=401 remote_addr=54.x.x.x time_ms=0 duration=120.507µs size=102 referer= handler=notfound
logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= t=2024-05-03T09:53:05.820389398Z level=info msg="Request Completed" method=GET path=/index.php/phpinfo status=302 remote_addr=54.x.x.x time_ms=0 duration=70.287µs size=29 referer= handler=notfound


i saw it shows database locked as
logger=sqlstore.transactions t=2024-05-03T11:36:34.901159296Z level=info msg="Database locked, sleeping then retrying" error="database is locked" retry=1 code="database is locked"
logger=sqlstore.transactions t=2024-05-03T11:36:34.913546808Z level=info msg="Database locked, sleeping then retrying" error="database is locked" retry=2 code="database is locked"

I'm trying to resolve this by passing env variables in helm values.yml as
 image:
  tag: 10.1.0
 env:
  GF_SECURITY_COOKIE_SAMESITE: disabled
  GF_SECURITY_COOKIE_SECURE: true
  GF_SECURITY_ALLOW_EMBEDDING: true

i have tried change the grafana version but still not working and aws ingress controller is showing unhealthy target. I'm using kube-prometheus-stack helm chart to deploy this grafana. below is values.yaml
 image:
  tag: 10.1.0
 env:
  GF_LOG_LEVEL: debug
 readinessProbe:
   httpGet:
    path: /api/health
    port: 3000

 livenessProbe:
   httpGet:
    path: /api/health
    port: 3000
   initialDelaySeconds: 30
   timeoutSeconds: 20
   failureThreshold: 10
 persistence:
  type: pvc
  enabled: true
  storageClassName: standard
  accessModes:
   - ReadWriteOnce
  size: 1Gi
 
 ingress:
   enabled: true
   annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:00000000000:certificate/288888bd2-c97d-433c-55555-400000000
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/subnets: "subnet-1,subnet-2,subnet-3" 
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: ms
   rules:
     - host: grafana.dev.developer.com
       http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            service:
              name: kube-stack-prometheus-grafana
              port:
                number: 80
          path: /
          pathType: Prefix

please help me to fix this
